# Store fingerprints in firebase through Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, store

I am creating an android apps and I want to store fingerprints in Firebase Database. How can I store figerprints in Firebase Database through Android Studio 3.0.1?

Comment: give more details

Comment: What do you mean by "store fingerprints"?

Comment: You want to store fingerprints from the users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get fingerprint template or image from android Fingerprint API. Fingerprint data are stored in a secure place by android system and are not accessible.

But you can ask the system to authenticate the user.

Here [sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog)

The doc, in section [Fingerprint Authentication](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html)